# Cannot use screen capture apps in Wayland

Tags: 18.04, screenshot, wayland, shutter

I have Ubuntu 18.04 (updated from 17.10 where I had the same problem), and when I use it with Wayland, I cannot use any screen capturing/recording apps. For instance, when I try to take a screenshot with Shutter, I get a weird pattern instead of what's actually on my screen:
[image: shutter]

I know I can just switch to GNOME/Ubuntu on Xorg, but sometimes that's not an option. Is there a fix for this? Or a certain app that works as it should on Wayland?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default *Screenshot* (`gnome-screenshot`) application should work fine. Search for it in the "*Activities*" overview or use the <kbd>Prt Sc</kbd> key. You can capture your whole screen just by running

```
gnome-screenshot
```

For the GUI, run

```
gnome-screenshot -i
```

Run

```
gnome-screenshot -h
```

to see all possible options.

Comment: Thank you, no idea how I didn't think of the default app. Do you have any idea as to why these apps don't work on Wayland though?

Comment: Additionally, what should I use for recording the screen? SimpleScreenRecorder only seems to capture a black screen and my cursor.

Comment: @IoanaAlexandru Simple answer is those applications are not written for Wayland yet. Applications which are not compatible with Wayland yet run under a XWayland compatibility layer. But advanced applications, which depend on and/or control X11 server "too much" (screen-capturing/recording etc.), might fail to run in a Wayland session (Wayland has a stricter security policy). If you use Skype you would find the screen-sharing option doesn't work in Wayland, but works in Xorg.

Comment: @IoanaAlexandru Same issue with screen-recording apps. [Green Recorder](https://github.com/foss-project/green-recorder) *claims* to be Wayland compatible, but I have seen others complaining about its performance in a Wayland session (haven't tried it myself).

Answer (score 0):

I use `grim -g "$(slurp)" - | wl-copy` to take an area of a screen and put it in clipboard.
Works perfectly in Sway on Arch Linux.

Comment: I don't think `grim` is available in repos of any of the currently supported Ubuntu releases.

Comment: grim is in the repos since 19.10 atleast.

Comment: err, what do you do with it after its in the clipboard? How do you save it to say ~/tmp?

Comment: @RichieHH sometimes you don't want to save it, just paste into some chat or program or whatever

Comment: Sure, but I cant help but think a tmp copy as a file does  no harm ;) Also I must admit I never once in my life "pasted" an image! I need to look into that ;)