# None of my installed apps can capture my whole screen

Tags: 19.10, screen, ffmpeg, video-streaming, obs-studio

When I try to stream on discord or OBS, I select the option to capture my entire screen. The only thing it shows is the cursor on a black screen. I have ffmpeg installed and I'm running Ubuntu 19.10. I can capture windows perfectly fine, but not the whole screen. Please help :/

PS. Sorry if this is a stupid question, I'm fairly new to Ubuntu

Comment: When you are entering your password at login, click the little gear icon. Select an X session (NOT a Wayland session). Applications in Wayland (including screen capture applications) do not have permission to see anything outside their own window. It's a tenacious design issue that developers have been wrangling with for a couple years.

Comment: @user535733 Tysm! This completely fixed my problem :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot use screen capture apps in Wayland](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036570/cannot-use-screen-capture-apps-in-wayland)

Comment: @user535733 It turns out I completely forgot I was using wayland

Comment: That happens. I have enjoyed using Wayland for years.

Comment: @user535733 Honestly I'm not sure what the difference is I probably should look that up