# Ubuntu 21.04 shutter did not work without X11 server

Tags: 21.04, shutter

I installed shutter 0.97 version

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/shutter
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install shutter
```

and

```
sudo apt install gnome-web-photo
```

but faced with error when try to screen selection

```
can't take screenshots without X11 server
```

how to fix it ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot use screen capture apps in Wayland](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036570/cannot-use-screen-capture-apps-in-wayland)

Answer (score 13):

I found a solution. In this file `sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf` uncomment this line `WaylandEnable=false` save and exit. Then run this command in the terminal `sudo systemctl restart gdm3`  Happy Ubuntu :)

Comment: ***IMPORTANT*** Please note that the PPA has changed.  See https://launchpad.net/~shutter/+archive/ubuntu/ppa Thank you - this worked for me on a greenfield install of Ubuntu 21.04.

Comment: You saved  my day! :) Thanks.

Comment: I can confirm this also works in Ubuntu 21.10.

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 21.10. Don't be like me not closing your apps. Or the restart command will do it for you :)

Comment: Amazing! Thanks!

Comment: confirm it on ubuntu 22.10

Answer (score 0):

Here's my work-around: [Ubuntu 22.04: How to rapidly take a screenshot, save it as a JPG, and edit it using the Shutter program to add highlighting](https://askubuntu.com/a/1446364/327339): use the new Ubuntu 22.04 screenshot tool, but edit it in Shutter.